# Acess and alter multiple elements of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

Is there some away in c++ to acess multiple elements of a matrix?

For example:

```
Matrix A = [1 2 3
            4 5 6
            7 8 9];

Matrix B = [10 11
            12 13];

A(row(1, 2), column(1, 2)) = B; /* After that A should be: [10 11 3
                                                            12 13 6
                                                             7  8 9] */
```

Please desconsidere the syntax, I thought it would be the simpliest way to exemplify my question.

Comment: You'd be able to do something like that using iterators. It depends on what you were using for your `Matrix` class.

Comment: Not out of the box no, but there may be some helpful libraries.

Comment: You should try using Eigen, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org , it's a pretty darn good library, small and super fast. It allows you to do these kind of things, in particular, here you can see a comparison between MATLAB-like syntax and Eigen syntax: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt